# Почему скрытый элемент при активном методе toggle отображается, как inline?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть галерея, которую хочу открывать при нажатии на стрелку и закрывать при нажатии на другую. Не могу понять, почему, когда когда к скрытой стрелке применяется метод `toggle` оно отображает элемент, как `inline`, а не `block`, хотя он изначально предопределен как блочный и как это можно исправить?
[фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/hg6mmgcw/)

```js
 $('#arrow-slide1').click(function() {
   $('#gallary-hide1').toggle(200);
   $('#arrow-slide1').toggle();
   $('#arrow-slide1-up').toggle();
 });
```

```css
.gallary-hide {
  display: none;
}
.arrow-slide {
  background: #fff url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.arrow-slide-up {
  background: #fff url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png") no-repeat;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="arrow-slide1" class="arrow-slide"></span><span id="gallary-hide1" class="gallary-hide">[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="2" gal_title="party"]</span><span id="arrow-slide1-up" class="arrow-slide arrow-slide-up"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toggle не учитывает какой параметр display стоит в стилях у элемента.

Используйте [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

**html**

```
<span class="myspan span-hidden">test</span>
```

**css**

```
.myspan{
    display: block;
}
.myspan.span-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
  $(".myspan").toggleClass('span-hidden');
```

Comment: или оказывается проще - заменить `span` на `div`